# SSRS report based on xml data

Tags: sql, xml, pdf, reporting-services

I referred to the below link in my research 
[Create Microsoft SQL Report (SSRS) based on XML data stored in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465011/create-microsoft-sql-report-ssrs-based-on-xml-data-stored-in-database)

If I use the xml in example for the link above (creating a dataset and using datasource as xml datasource and in the text command copying the text) it works however it does not work for the xml which is formatted as follows.

```
<Query>
<XmlData>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ConfigurationData 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Name>MIT 3</Name>
<Description>MIT Uni 3</Description>
<RunLocation>5</RunLocation>
<NamingConvention />
<PollingPeriod>-1</PollingPeriod>
<SetLocationAtRuntime>false</SetLocationAtRuntime>
</XmlData>
</Query>
```

If I remove the top section (as below) then I can only see the very first field "Name" in the dataset fields.  I would like to see all fields.

```
<Query>
<XmlData>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Name>MIT 3</Name>
<Description>MIT Uni 3</Description>
<RunLocation>5</RunLocation>
<NamingConvention />
<PollingPeriod>-1</PollingPeriod>
<SetLocationAtRuntime>false</SetLocationAtRuntime>
</XmlData>
</Query>
```